# How to input to vector correctly in C++

Tags: c++

When I try to input to vector by following code, I get a `segmentation fault` as shown below.
I defined the vector and set `N`, and tried to input a vector with `N` elements.
What is the root cause of this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int N;
vector<int> A(N);
int main(){
    cin>>N;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) cin>>A[i];
}
```

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-187 ]$ ./vector_input 
1
1
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You need to declare or resize the vector *after* you've read `N`. Right now, since `N` is a global variable it is initialized to 0, so the size of the vector is 0. You could also read the data into a temporary variable and use `A.push_back(temp);` to add it to the end of the vector.

Comment: Correct is to always check result of every operation with input stream because the input data can come from either dumb or evil user or from program written by dumb or evil programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because constructor of `A` is called with `N=0`. When you input `N`, it doesn't affect the vector at all. If you really want to keep using globals, then use `std::vector::resize` but the recommended way would be:

```
int main(){
    std::size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> A(n);
    for(auto & x : A) std::cin >> x;
}
```

Comment: The code in the question does **not** call the vector constructor with `N=0`, it calls it with an unitialized `N`! This could be any random value previously in there.

Comment: @codeling `N` is static in the given code and therefore it'll be initialized to `0`, not garbage. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

Comment: ah, missed that, yes, thanks for the clarification! the wonders of c++ initialization ;)

Answer (score 1):

This happened because `N` was never initialized and it was used for initiating `vector`. So, your code produces [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

You need to take input first, and then initialize the `vector`.
Also, avoid using `using namespace std;`. And there's no real need to initialize `A` and `N` in a global scope.

**NOTE: To avoid undefined behavior further you enable this flag while compiling C++ programs.**

```
-fsanitize=undefined,address
```

Code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::vector<int> A(N);
    for(auto &i : A)
        std::cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `N` used for initialization is not initialized

```
int main(){
    int n,a;
    vector<int> vec;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a;
       vec.push_back(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post doesn't add anything new, which isn't mentioned in above answers.